# How to turn off Gnome's keyboard-touchpad auto disabling on "2 in 1" laptop?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, touchpad

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5 laptop, a so called "2 in 1" model where you can turn the screen around and use the machine in tablet mode. Gnome can detect turning the screen and disables the keyboard & touchpad when it believes the machine is in tablet mode. The problem is that it is often wrong about its believes and disables the keyboard when I want to use it.

This was mildly inconvenient under Ubuntu 20.10, but since I upgraded to 21.04 the problem got worse. Now I often end up in a state where the keyboard works but the touchpad is disabled.

Since I don't really need the tablet mode, I would like to disable this entire feature and just keep my peripherals always on. However, I don't even know the feature's name. Could someone give me some pointers on how to do this?

Comment: Fixing the auto-disable feature would be even better, but I suspect there's some HW issue with the sensor. With `evtest` I see the events when moving the screen, they just come at the wrong point:

`Event: time 1624904646.777369, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value f3`
`Event: time 1624904646.777369, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 191 (KEY_F21), value 1`
`Event: time 1624904646.777369, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------`
`Event: time 1624904646.784424, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value f3`
`Event: time 1624904646.784424, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 191 (KEY_F21), value 0`

Comment: Please use [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1348770/edit) to add new information.  As a comment, the information you posted is practically illegible (impossible to parse)